# What 12 hex digits color codes in xfce terminal configuration means?

Tags: colors, terminal, terminal-emulator, xfce

Recently I set up my XFCE terminal to use the perfect palette of 
[Solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) using this [prepared config](https://github.com/sgerrand/xfce4-terminal-colors-solarized).

All works fine (although midnight commander colors make me cry now) but one thing is really curious to me:

Why do color codes in xfce terminal settings contain 12 hex digits rather than 6? Like these one:

```
ColorPalette8=#d3d3d7d7cfcf
```

What does it mean? And how is it related to color codes specified on 
[official page](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized#the-values)

Comment: Is this really a coding question? I'm failing to see the relevance to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hmm.. Truly probably it'd fit SuperUser better

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GTK uses 16 bits per colour channel, i.e. 4 hex digits. A colour value for GTK can be encoded as `#rgb`, `#rrggbb` or `#rrrrggggbbbb`.

Comment: Wow, Thanks! Sorry for late acceptance. I though this question will remain unanswered forever.